Eclipse how do i close this window?
Just wondering how can I close this window  which is part of Debug Perspective - and keep it closed for good?

This is some thing new that I see now.  I have not seen it in the past.  All I can do is to minimize it - but when I try to view a JAVA file, it opens again.
Thanks.
I am using Eclipse 2023-12 (4.30.0) Build 20231201-2043

Your screenshot shows the empty editor area of the Debug perspective. The editor area cannot be closed. Before Eclipse 2023-06 no shortcut hints, so-called onboarding information were shown in the empty editor area. By the way, Eclipse 2023-12 is three releases behind. Please upgrade.

@howlger - That explains it.  I moved all source panels to the editor area of the Debug perspective.  And I will upgrade to latest Eclipse once I have a breather.  Thanks, again.

Your screenshot shows the empty editor area of the Debug perspective. The editor area cannot be closed, it's just a part of the main window.
In the past the background of the editor area was empty. In Eclipse 2023-06 (4.28) the so-called onboarding information for the empty editor area has been introduced.
